# Pandas: Generate column on groupby and value_counts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Goal is to generate a column `pct` group by `id` where `'pct'` = `(1st value of 'pts' group by 'id'` * `100)` / `number of same consecutive 'id' value where 'x' and 'y' both are 'NaN'`. For e.g. when `id=1`, `pct` = `(5*100) / 2 = 250`. It will loop through whole dataframe.

Sample df:

```
   id pts   x       y
0   1   5   NaN     NaN
1   1   5   1.0     NaN
2   1   5   NaN     NaN
3   2   8   NaN     NaN
4   2   8   2.0     1.0
5   3   7   NaN     NaN
6   3   7   NaN     5.0
7   3   7   NaN     NaN
8   3   7   NaN     NaN
9   4   1   NaN     NaN
```

Expected Output:

```
   id pts   x       y       pct
0   1   5   NaN     NaN     250
1   1   5   1.0     NaN     250
2   1   5   NaN     NaN     250
3   2   8   NaN     NaN     800
4   2   8   2.0     1.0     800
5   3   7   NaN     NaN     233
6   3   7   NaN     5.0     233
7   3   7   NaN     NaN     233
8   3   7   NaN     NaN     233
9   4   1   NaN     NaN     100
```

I tried:

```
df['pct'] = df.groupby('id')['pts']/df.groupby('id')['x']['y'].count(axis=1)* 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
df['pct'] = df['id'].map(df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x['pts'].iloc[0] * 100 // x[['x', 'y']].isna().sum(axis=1).eq(2).sum()))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   id  pts    x    y  pct
0   1    5  NaN  NaN  250
1   1    5  1.0  NaN  250
2   1    5  NaN  NaN  250
3   2    8  NaN  NaN  800
4   2    8  2.0  1.0  800
5   3    7  NaN  NaN  233
6   3    7  NaN  5.0  233
7   3    7  NaN  NaN  233
8   3    7  NaN  NaN  233
9   4    1  NaN  NaN  100
```

#### Explanation

```
>>> df[['x', 'y']]
     x    y
0  NaN  NaN
1  1.0  NaN
2  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN
4  2.0  1.0
5  NaN  NaN
6  NaN  5.0
7  NaN  NaN
8  NaN  NaN
9  NaN  NaN
```

First, we create a mask of the selected `x` and `y` columns where each value is `True` if it's not NaN and `False` if it is NaN:

```
>>> df[['x', 'y']].isna()
0   True   True
1  False   True
2   True   True
3   True   True
4  False  False
5   True   True
6   True  False
7   True   True
8   True   True
9   True   True
```

Next, we count how many NaNs were in each row by summing horizontally. Since `True` is interepreted as `1` and `False` as `0`, this will work:

```
>>> df[['x', 'y']].isna().sum(axis=1)
0    2
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    0
5    2
6    1
7    2
8    2
9    2
```

Then, we count how many rows had 2 NaN values (2 because `x` and `y` are 2 columns):

```
>>> df[['x', 'y']].isna().sum(axis=1).eq(2)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
6    False
7     True
8     True
9     True
```

Finally, we count how many `True` values there were (a `True` value means that row contained only NaNs), by summing the `True` values again:

```
>>> df[['x', 'y']].isna().sum(axis=1).eq(2).sum()
7
```

Of course, we do this in a `.groupby(...).apply(...)` call, so this code gets executed for each group of `id`, not across the whole dataframe like this explanation has done. But the concepts are identical:

```
>>> df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x[['x', 'y']].isna().sum(axis=1).eq(2).sum())
id
1    2
2    1
3    3
4    1
dtype: int64
```

So for `id = 1`, 2 rows have `x` and `y` NaN. For `id = 2`, 1 row has `x` and `y` NaN. And so on...

---

The other (first) part of the code in the groupby call:

```
x['pts'].iloc[0] * 100
```

All it does is, for each group, it selects the 0th (first) value, and multiplies it by 100:

```
>>> df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x['pts'].iloc[0] * 100)
id
1    500
2    800
3    700
4    100
dtype: int64
```

Combined with the other code just explained:

```
>>> df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x['pts'].iloc[0] * 100 // x[['x', 'y']].isna().sum(axis=1).eq(2).sum())
id
1    250
2    800
3    233
4    100
dtype: int64
```

Finally, we map the values in `id` to the values we've just computed (notice in the above that the numbers are indexes by the values of `id`):

```
>>> df['id']
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
7    3
8    3
9    4
Name: id, dtype: int64

>>> computed = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x['pts'].iloc[0] * 100 // x[['x', 'y']].isna().sum(axis=1).eq(2).sum())
>>> computed
id
1    250
2    800
3    233
4    100
dtype: int64

>>> df['id'].map(computed)
0    250
1    250
2    250
3    800
4    800
5    233
6    233
7    233
8    233
9    100
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Would you please explain `.sum(axis=1).eq(2).sum()` this part of these code?

Comment: Yes! Give me a few minutes :)

Comment: Check the answer now. It has a long, detailed explanation. :)